# What are the significances of chromosome mapping?

Tags: homework, molecular-genetics, chromosome

The few point that I have come across are:

The following are the significances of chromosome mapping:

1. Chromosome maps help identify the location of gene of interest on a chromosome for genetic studies.
2. It helps to locate the region of a chromosome surgery.
3. Maps of the animals chromosome provides methods to study evolution process.

Can somebody add some more points to this answer?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you ask about genetic mapping which has been demonstrated in the HGP (human genome project).

The human genome project:

- enabled humans to find the gene responsible for relatively rare, single-gene inherited disorders such as cystic fibrosis and Duchenne muscular dystrophy
- is useful in guiding scientists to the many genes that are believed to play a role in the development of more common disorders such as asthma, heart disease, diabetes, cancer, and psychiatric conditions
- allows the production of new drugs based on DNA base sequences of genes or the structure of proteins coded for by these genes
- gives the chance to study migration patterns of humans and origins
- improved knowledge of the evolutionary relationships between humans and other organisms, which will help to develop better, more accurate classification systems

<sub>Sources:</sub>

- <sub>https://www.genome.gov/10000715/genetic-mapping-fact-sheet/</sub>
- <sub>https://www.genome.gov/12011238/an-overview-of-the-human-genome-project/</sub>
- <sub>https://www.genome.gov/10001772/all-about-the--human-genome-project-hgp/</sub>

Comment: nice answer, but I think that OP asked for chromosome mapping (general), not HGP.

Comment: Yes that is correct I asked for chromosome mapping in general, still thank you for your efforts.